# Trying to understand Python Beautiful Soup parsing code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I came across the following code, which I found very useful, but wasn't sure how to interpret one piece of it.

```
from pprint import pprint
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2014'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

headers = ['Opening', 'Title', 'Genre', 'Director', 'Cast']
results = {}

for block in soup.select('div#mw-content-text > h3'):
    title = block.find('span', class_='mw-headline').text
    rows = block.find_next_sibling('table', class_='wikitable').find_all('tr')

    results[title] = [{header: td.text for header, td in zip(headers, row.find_all('td'))}
                      for row in rows[1:]]

pprint(results)
```

I understand all of it except this piece:

```
    results[title] = [{header: td.text for header, td in zip(headers, row.find_all('td'))}
                      for row in rows[1:]]
```

Can anyone explain what this is doing and how I should read it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one line can be basically broken down into this.

```
for count, row in enumerate(rows[1:]):
    for header, td in zip(headers, row.find_all('td'):
        results[title][count][header] = td.text
```